# add last item from Json array

Tags: json, laravel, api

[image]

this is my control in laravel

```
function addgat(Request $request)
{

    $gat=gatmodel::create($request->all());
    return response()->json($gat,200);

}
```

problem is when i try to add array of json to my backend its laravel api to connect with mysql database add only last item in json array

Answer (score 0):

In order for that to work, you have to send the variable key name as

```
gat_name[]
```

instead of

```
gat_name
```

Comment: thanks all to answer i post request but api only store last item from request

Comment: when i use {"gat_name":["ahmed65","ahmed66"]} its gave erorr 500

Answer (score 0):

hello all thank you for looking for my question but solve it is up with

change (create to insert)